# Unable to write html content in an excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I've created a tiny script in python to scrape the first title and it's description from a website and write the same in an excel file using `openpyxl` library. The important thing to notice here is that I wish to save the title as text but the description as raw html content, not text.

I've tried like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
wb = Workbook()
wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])

def fetch_content(link):
    req = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("#questions .summary .question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
    desc = soup.select_one("#questions .summary")

    ws.append([title,desc])
    print(title,desc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws = wb.create_sheet("output")
    ws.append(['Title','Description'])
    fetch_content(link)
    wb.save("SO.xlsx")
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <div class="summary"> -----so on
```

Expected output in that excel file (both truncated):

```
How to scrape data   <div class="summary">
```

Comment: ***"description as raw html content"***: You have to cast it to `str` first.Read [output](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output)

Comment: It's a damn good answer I came across in years @stovfl. Yes, it did the trick wonderfully. This is how I did it `ws.append([title,str(desc)])` complying your suggestion. You wanna post it as an answer so that others might find it useful as I tried searching a lot to find similar answer in google but no cigar. Btw, in csv I could notice that I can dump it directly, right? Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution. ***"in csv ... I can dump it directly,"***: In `CSV` all have to be `str`, `str(<object>`) on non `str` objects is the default.

Comment: You're expecting openpyxl to know how to handle parser objects, but it doesn't: this is your responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stovfl and robot.txt made the perfect solution.  I took the liberty to post the answer since I often forget this approach.

```
def fetch_content(link):
    req = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("#questions .summary .question-  hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
    desc = soup.select_one("#questions .summary")

    ws.append([title,str(desc)]) #cast desc to str
    print(title,desc)
```